# How to eliminate the denominator in the calculation of the Lagrange interpolation on a finite field?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, lagrange-interpolation

I am studying Secret Sharing by looking at the lecture notes here:

[https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/teaching/cs70-s08/notes/n10.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Edaw/teaching/cs70-s08/notes/n10.pdf)

But I could not understand why the following congruence equation holds in the part where the Lagrange interpolation is calculated on a finite field:

\begin{align*}
\frac{(x-4)(x-5)}{2} \equiv 4(x-4)(x-5)\space (mod\space 7)
\end{align*}

I would be very grateful if someone could give me a detailed explanation.

Comment: $\bmod 7\!:\ \,2\cdot 4 \equiv 1\,$ so $\, \dfrac{1}2 := 2^{-1}\equiv 4.\,$ See the linked dupes on modular fractions and inverses.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you for pointed out. Figured out how to do modular fractions arithmetic.

Comment: Great, glad it helped.